# Use only 2 elements from the collection in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way how to use only 2 or any other specific number of elements from a collection in Razor View?
I would like to use something like this in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Authors.Take(2))
```

I know I can achieve this by creating a new property on a model and specifying the rule there but that's not what I am looking for. As in my case there are a lot of views for this particular model and each takes different number of elements.

I am also interested in knowing why the example above doesn't work. 
Thanks

Comment: More to the point... when you populate the model to be displayed in the view... why don't you just populate the model with what you actually want displayed in the view?

Comment: You could find a solution by using Display Templates http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by looping model array.
Something like this:

```
@for(int i=0; i < YOUR_SPECIFED_AMOUNT_OF_ELEMENT; i++){
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Authors[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the example you provided to work if you define a diplay template for the type of the element in `Authors` collection (let's assumet that the type is `Author`). If you then have an `IEnumerable<Author>` (or implementing type like `List<Author>`, etc.), MVC framework should then use that display template *for each element* of that collection by itself (since that is default behaviour / default display template for `DisplayFor` of a collection).

So assuming that `Author` is defined as such:

```
public class Author {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And you defined display template ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate/Author.cshtml as such:

```
@model Author
@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.LastName)
```

Then if you used the code from your example, I would suppose the resulting HTML in your example would be the same / similar as if you used instead:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.Authors.First())
@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.Authors.Skip(1).First())
```

Or:

```
@foreach(Author author in Model.Authors.Take(2)) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(author => author)
}
```